# Mechanical wave propagation in solids

Tags: waves

What frequency of a mechanical wave travels farthest in solids. Let assume I have a solid 5 km long, what wave frequency gets to the other end with the minimum waveform loss and energy loss?

Answer (score 1):

Zero, or arbitrarily close to it. A very low frequency corresponds to rigid body motion - you can expect the far end to move faithfully (with a delay corresponding to the speed of sound in the material), with no possibility of resonance or structural damping, both of which would dissipate  energy or even damage the material by exceeding its strength.

Comment: In essence it's a bad idea?